# How can an instance add itself to a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I need to instantiate a class `SpriteWithTimer` and that the new object adds itself to a vector `vsprites`.

Here's a code snippet:

```cpp
#include <vector>
...
class SpriteWithTimer {
   public:
   SpriteWithTimer();
   ~SpriteWithTimer();
   ...
};
static std::vector<SpriteWithTimer> vsprites;

int main()
{
   ...
}
...
SpriteWithTimer::SpriteWithTimer(){
        ...
        vsprites.push_back(this);
   };
```

but I've got his error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<SpriteWithTimer>::push_back(SpriteWithTimer*)’
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=SpriteWithTimer, _Alloc=std::allocator<SpriteWithTimer>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (SpriteWithTimer *) -- object type is: std::vector<SpriteWithTimer, std::allocator<SpriteWithTimer>>
```

thanks!

Comment: Use the "std::vector<SpriteWithTimer*> vsprites" and store only pointers, not the objects themselves.

Comment: @DanielLangr it seems to me the right solution (to store a pointer to that object, as VictorLatypov suggested). I would validate it if it was a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object stored inside a vector is always a brand new separately-constructed object. Therefore, you **can't store to a vector an object created elsewhere**. Either, you can store:

1. a **copy of that object**: `push_back(*this)`,
2. an object with the **content moved from that object**: `push_back(std::move(*this))`,
3. a **pointer to that object** `push_back(this)`.

You need to choose what is suitable in your case. In the third case, beware of *dangling pointers*. Basically, you should guarantee that the lifetime of the pointed-to objects will not end before these pointers are used.

Comment: The title is "an instance add itself to a vector". If this condition is ignored, maybe a more general situation similar to point 3, using `std::unique_ptr` as commented by @dfrib, is like `static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> vec; vec.emplace_back(new Foo());`

Comment: @rustyhu Do you suggest ignoring the very essence of the OP's question? They obviously add into a vector from a member function invoked on that instance.

Comment: @rustyhu Also, note that `vec.emplace_back(new Foo());` is very wrong. If `emplace_back` threw an exception, you would end up with resource leak. There is no way how to delete that temporary in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

#### A vector of `Foo` objects?

If you want a vector of, say `Foo` objects (and not *pointers* to `Foo` objects), you would need to dereference the `this` *pointer* within the member function that is intended to *copy* the object to the pass-in non-const container reference. E.g.:

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    int x{42};
    void addMeToVector(std::vector<Foo>& v) & { 
        // _copies_ the `Foo` object in v
        v.push_back(*this); 
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    Foo f1{};
    f1.addMeToVector(v);
}
```

Note that we have applied the *ref-qualifier* `&` to the `addMeToVector` member function, to avoid a temporary object attempting to add themselves to a vector argument:

```
Foo{}.addMeToVector(v);
// error: 'this' argument to member function 'addMeToVector' 
//         is an rvalue, but function has non-const lvalue ref-qualifier
```

as this could arguable be unexpected as compared to directly pushing back (or emplacing) temporary objects directly into the container.

If you actually want to explicitly allow *moving* say temporary object into the container via a member function, and for some reason do not want to directly use the `push_back(T&&)` overload from the vector, you could add an overload for `&&`-qualifiers:

```
struct Foo {
    int x{42};
    void addMeToVector(std::vector<Foo>& v) & {
        // copies in (push_back(const T&) overload)
        v.push_back(*this); 
    }
    void addMeToVector(std::vector<Foo>& v) && { 
        // moves in (push_back(T&&) overload)
        v.push_back(std::move(*this)); 
    }
};
```

This overload scheme would allow moving in temporary objects, wheres lvalues would be copied in.

You could also move in non-temporary objects, but this could lead to some lifetime confusion on the call site, as callee object (an lvalue) would move itself into the argument passed to it, and should no longer be used after that *member function call*, which would be quite a weird (and unexpected) semantic.

---

#### A vector of pointers to `Foo` objects?

> [...] I needed a vector of pointers, not the object itself.

If you consider each `Foo` object as unique, and that *ownership* of it should be likewise unique (and e.g. shifted to the vector when adding `Foo` objects to it), you may want to re-consider if objects themselves really *need* to be able to add themselves to a container, and use a container of `std::unique_pointer`:s instead of a raw pointers. As raw pointers do not, by themselves, hold any information about ownership, they typically come with lifetime issues if not handled with care.

Comment: Note that in this program the object whose member function is called will not be in that vector. A copy of that object will be in that vector instead.

Comment: @eerorika Expanded with an `&&`-ref-qualified overload that moves the object into the vector.

Comment: Well, I guess my question wasn't the good one... I needed a vector of **pointers**, not the object itself. Since I'm a noob, I didn't use the good technical terms.

Comment: @ThePhi if you consider each sprite object as unique, and that _ownership_ of it should be likewise unique (and e.g. shifted to the vector when adding sprite objects to it), you may want to use `std::unique_pointer` instead of a raw pointer. As raw pointers do not, by themselves, hold any information about ownership, they typically come with lifetime issues if not handled with care.

Comment: How would you add a pointer to an existing object to the vector of unique pointers? What if, for example, this object has an automatic storage duration? There is no generic way how to find this out from within the object itself.

Comment: @DanielLangr The last paragraph was intended to go beyond the possible XY problem of the OP (due to the notorious lifetime issues of raw pointers), but I was not really clear on that. Expanded the last paragraph to be clear that this would apply if the requirements of "adding itself to a container" can be removed. Thanks.